# How to cascade unknown number of conditions in Spark without looping through each condition

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to filter a data frame based on processed user queries, however the number of conditions are not constant and will change user by user. For example lets assume, Two user will have the following different conditions

```
1- df.filter( ( col('A') == 'book' ) & (col('B') == '1') & (col('C') == '0') )
2- df.filter( ( col('A') == 'film') ) & (col('B') == '0'))
```

One solution is to cascade the conditions sequentially

```
for k,v in argList:
   df = df.filter(col(k) == v)
```

where argList is a list of conditions per user, for example
`[('A','book') ,('B','1'), ('C','0')]`  or `[('A','film') ,('B','0')]` , .....

Is there a better way to cascade multiple conditions without looping through every condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with looping through the conditions as the Spark optimzer will combine all filters into a single one:

```python
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,2),(1,4),(5,6)], ['A', 'B'])
df = df.filter(F.col('A') == 1)
df = df.filter(F.col('B') == 4)
df.explain()
```

prints

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Filter (((isnotnull(A#0L) AND isnotnull(B#1L)) AND (A#0L = 1)) AND (B#1L = 4))
+- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[A#0L,B#1L]
```

and only one filter operation is executed.